# Google +1 share dialog empty and bug

Tags: dialog, share

I insered the google +1 button in my page, and whene i click on it, the +1 works fine but the share dialog steel open with no content, until i click on other area in the page to make it dissapears

You have some idea why this not work plz ?

Comment: Please include some of your code; it will make it easier for us to help identify the cause of the issue.

Comment: Thank's Simon Martin for trying helping me, i found the problem and i solve it, i let the solution maybe other one need it in future.

The problem was the version of mootools i use in my website, it was the 1.2.4 version which overwrites the JSON object provided by the browser. The share dialog fails when trying to call JSON.

I edit the mootools js file, and added this code in the end 

JSON.parse = JSON.decode;
JSON.stringify = JSON.encode;

And now everythink work fine.

Answer (score 1):

Solved !

The problem was the version of mootools I use in my website, it was the 1.2.4 version which overwrites the JSON object provided by the browser. The share dialog fails when trying to call JSON.

I edit the mootools js file, and added this code in the end :

```
JSON.parse = JSON.decode;
JSON.stringify = JSON.encode;
```

Now everything works fine.